# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PermitsController#detail, Couldn't find Permit with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi guys I keep get this error when i try to access to render out one specific permit data from the permits model to the detail.html.erb, i search through all my code and couldn't find the bug. Can you guys help me to check which part i did wrong? Btw I'm implementing a website using Ruby on rails

This is my permits_controller.rb

```
class PermitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_permit, only: [:destroy]
  def index
    @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @permits = Permit.new
  end

  def create
    @permits = current_user.permits.build(permit_params)
    if @permits.save
      redirect_to invoice_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def destroy
    Permit.destroy_all(user_id: current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Permit was successfully canceled.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def confirm
    @fields = %i[vehicle_type, carplate, studentid, name, department, permitstart, permitend]
    @permit = current_user.permits.build(permit_params)
    render :new and return unless @permit.valid?
  end



  def show
    @permits = Permit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

  def update
    @permits = Permit.where(user_id: current_user).take
    respond_to do |format|
      if @permits.update(permit_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path}
        flash[:success] = "Permit successfully updated"
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
    #@permits = Permit.find_or_initialize_by(user_id: params[:id])
  end
  def detail
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_permit
    @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def permit_params
    params.require(:permit).permit(:vehicle_type, :name, :studentid, :department, :carplate, :duration, :permitstart, :permitend)
  end
end
```

Detail.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Permit') %>
<h1>Permit Application</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">


        <h2><%= @permits.permitstart %></h2>

  </div>
</div>
```

Route.db

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :permits do
    collection do
      post :confirm
    end
  end
  resources :visitor_permits
  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'viewpermit' =>'permits#detail'

  get 'invoice' => 'permits#invoice'
  get 'payment' =>'transaction#new'
  get 'show_visitor_permit' =>'visitor_permits#show'
  get 'show_permit' =>'permits#show'
  get 'visitorpermit' => 'visitor_permits#new'
  post 'createpermit' => 'permits#create'
  get 'homepage/index'
  post 'permits' => 'permits#create'
  get 'permitapplication' => 'permits#new'
  get 'adminlogin' => 'admin_controller#index'
  get 'patrollogin' => 'patrol_officer_controller#index'
  get 'createcitation' => 'citations#new'
  get 'contact'=> 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  post 'users' => 'users#create'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new' #Page for a new session
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create' #Create a new session
  delete 'logout'=>'sessions#destroy' #Delete a session


  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

This is my linking page (show.html.erb)

```
<h2>My Permits</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Permit Start Date</th>
    <th>Permit End Data</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th> </th>
  </tr>
<% @permits.each do |permit| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= permit.permitstart %></td>
    <td><%= permit.permitend %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Detail', viewpermit_path(permit) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_permit_path(permit) %></td>
  </tr>

<% end %>

</table>
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't exist a Permit with the id you are passing in.

Comment: Yea but the EDIT action in my controller actually perform the same thing also render out the data. Both of the action perform same thing the differences is EDIT render the data to a text field while the DETAIL render the data to the page as a plain text. I did the same thing as i did EDIT but it doesn't work

Comment: `detail` is a custom action. Did you setup your routes properly? How does your link look like?

Comment: Updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined your routes in a proper way. Your routes simply redirects to action `#detail` but you don't set your variables within the route. You have multiple options

```
resources :permits do
  collection do
    post :confirm
  end

  member do
    get 'viewpermit' # enables a route like /permits/1/viewpermit
  end
end

# or

get 'viewpermit/:id' => 'permits#detail' #enables route /viewpermit/1
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i got back this error NoMethodError in Permits#show

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more specific what you tried? The whole route example or only a part? What method is missing? `NoMethodError` normaly names a method which is missing. When do you get this error? Did you inspect your `Detail` link? How does this link look like?

Comment: I tried the 1st and 2nd solution which replace the get 'viewpermit' =>'permits#show' in my route file then i got this error Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/viewpermit.2"

Comment: Thats right because the route has to be `/viewpermit/2` did you try this url manuly or by following a link? How do you generate this url? Did you reload the page after changing routes?

Comment: By following a link, the link is at the show.html.erb - <td><%= link_to 'Detail', viewpermit_path(permit) %></td> i posted with my question. Yep i reload after i made change

Comment: Try ` viewpermit_path(id: permit.id)`

Comment: Man, it works!! Thank you so much you are absolutely a legend!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

In your `show` action.replace `where` to `find`

```
def show
  @permits = Permit.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: After replace, i get this new error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PermitsController#show
Couldn't find Permit with 'id'={:user_id=>1}. I think that the problem should be at the DETAIL action.